# Can't Create CSV file in Download folder in Android using Unity

Tags: android, csv, unity-game-engine, storage, file-permissions

I have added the following permissions:

android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.unity3d.player"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I can create CSV file Application.persistentDataPath but I can't create it in the Download folder.

**FileManager.cs**

```
public class FileManager : Singleton<FileManager>
{
    public TMP_Text Text, Text2,Text3, Text4;
    public List<RunnerData> Runners = new List<RunnerData>();

    private CSVWriter CSVWrite = new CSVWriter();
    private CSVReader CSVRead = new CSVReader();

    private void Start()
    {
        AndroidRuntimePermissions.Permission result = AndroidRuntimePermissions.RequestPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        if (result == AndroidRuntimePermissions.Permission.Granted)
        {
            CreateDirectory(GetDownloadFolder() + "/Cronoruners");
            Write(GetDownloadFolder() + "/Test.csv");
            Read(GetDownloadFolder() + "/Test.csv");
        }
    }

    public void Write(string path)
    {
        CSVWrite.WriteCSV(path, Runners);
        Text2.text = "CSV creado correctamente";
    }

    public void Read(string path)
    {
        Runners.Clear();
        Runners = CSVRead.ReadCSV(path);
        if (Runners.Count > 0)
            Text3.text = "CSV leido correctamente: " + Runners[0].Name;
        else
            Text3.text = "Error de lectura";
    }

    public void CreateDirectory(string dir)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            var directory = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            Text.text = "Directorio creado correctamente";
        }
        else
            Text.text = "Directorio ya existente";
    }

    public static string GetDownloadFolder()
    {
        string[] temp = (Application.persistentDataPath.Replace("Android", "")).Split(new string[] { "//" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

        return (temp[0] + "/Download");
    }

    private string GetTime(int hour, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        return hour + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}
```

**CSVWriter.cs**

```
public class CSVWriter
{
    public void WriteCSV(string path, List<RunnerData> Runners)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file);
        if (Runners.Count > 0)
        {
            sw.Write("Dorsal" + "," + "Nombre" + "," + "Marca");
            for (int i = 0; i < Runners.Count; i++)
            {
                sw.Write("\r\n" + Runners[i].Dorsal + "," + Runners[i].Name + "," + Runners[i].Time);
            }
        }

        sw.Close();
        file.Close();   
    }
}
```

**CSVReader.cs**

```
public class CSVReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<RunnerData> ReadCSV(string path)
    {
        List<RunnerData> runners = new List<RunnerData>();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file);

            bool endfile = false;
            int runnersCount = -1;
            while (!endfile)
            {
                runnersCount++;
                string data = sr.ReadLine();
                if (data == null)
                {
                    endfile = true;
                    break;
                }
                var values = data.Split(',');
                runners.Add(new RunnerData());
                runners[runnersCount].Dorsal = values[0];
                runners[runnersCount].Name = values[1];
                runners[runnersCount].Time = "00:00:00";
            }
            sr.Close();
            file.Close();
            return runners;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**RunnerData.cs**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class RunnerData
{
    public string Dorsal;
    public string Name;
    public string Time;
}
```

I tried to change "install location" and "write access" parameters on the Player Settings too.

Can you help me?

Comment: There is no reason why you should not be able to create a file there.

Comment: Recently, I have added screenshots of my scripts. Do you see any error?

Comment: Please remove pictures. Post codeand other info as text. That is how it goes here.